# Concatenate variable name in python

Tags: python, r

I have a set of table names

```
1. EOM
2.STMT
3.LOOKUP etc
```

I want to associate these table names with some variables names such as

```
1. start_time, 
2. end_time, 
3. total_time etc.
```

The way I want to write these variable names is something like

```
1. start_time_EOM, end_time_EOM, total_time_EOM
2. start_time_STMT, end_time_STMT,total_time_STMT
3. start_time_LOOKUP,end_time_LOOKUP,total_time_LOOKUP
```

Can this be done in python, and how?
(Note: I am new to Python, and still trying to learn).

Comment: use a dictionary

Comment: Are you using a library like Pandas or something? You mentioned tables...

Comment: Yes, it can be done by polluting `globals()` and no, you should not be doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, dictionaries are solution:

```
tables=["A","B","C"]
vars = ["var1","var2","var3"]
dict={}
for val in tables:
  for val2 in vars:
    dict[val2+"_"+val] = foo
    dict[val2+"_"+val] = bar
    dict[val2+"_"+val] = foobar
#and so
```

Hope if helps

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very helpful.
Question: How can the same problem be solved in R?

Comment: @Gompu Sorry, IDK about R. Hope you find the solution. Greetings!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change variables names the way you are looking to do, but you might try using a python dictionary to achieve what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: you could probably jury-rig something using `eval()` but Cary is right, you *really* don't want to do it this way.

Comment: Thank you so much! How can the same problem be solved in R?